# pulling items only from few lists usign content query webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have 9 lists. But i want to pulling items only from 5 lists using content Query Webpart. Can anybody please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListsOverride` to specify the lists. Example:

```
<property name="ListsOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<Lists><List ID="31A7C09D-52CC-4585-B998-A3F180A9BD07"/><List ID="7382D66D-2E4C-47CB-A95C-5EECD68F5E61"/></Lists> ]]></property>
```

See this for more information: http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/06/querying-specific-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part.html

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy using CQWP

1. Add a Content Query Web Part to a page in the site. Bydefault the CQWP will display all of the pages in the site.
2. Now choose to Modify the Shared Web Part and in the Web Part Tool Pane, **expand Query and change the Source list** from where you want to get the data.**You have to choose option 3.(Show Items from following list)**

[image]